# What are the correct flags to rsync to locally mounted S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, rsync, s3fs

I have an S3 bucket mounted locally at `/mnt/s3` using `s3fs`.

I can manually `cp -r /my-dir/. /mnt/s3`, and the file `testfile.txt` in `/mnt/s3` will be overwritten as expected, without error.

However, when using `rsync` to do this, I get errors about unlinking and copying if the file already exists in the bucket. (If a file of the same name *does not* exist in the bucket, it's copied properly, without any errors.)

```
$ rsync -vr --temp-dir=/tmp/rsync /my-dir/. /mnt/s3

sending incremental file list
testfile.txt
rsync: unlink "/mnt/s3/testfile.txt": Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: copy "/tmp/rsync/testfile.txt.Kkyy5n" -> "testfile.txt": Operation not permitted (1)

sent 274 bytes  received 428 bytes  1,404.00 bytes/sec
total size is 95  speedup is 0.14
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1178) [sender=3.1.2]
```

I'm using `--temp-dir` because otherwise `rsync` was copying temporary files into `/mnt/s3` and trying to rename them to their permanent names. However, `rsync` failed to rename them, and also failed to delete the temporary files, resulting in improperly copied files and lots of clutter in the S3 bucket.

Comment: Side-note: Amazon S3 is an object storage service. It is not intended to be "mounted". Utilities like `s3fs` cannot fully present S3 as a filesystem. It's possibly a good way to transfer data, but is not advisable for Production usage. You could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 sync` command instead.

Comment: Which version of s3fs did you test with and on which operating system?  I successfully rsynced a directory with modified files with 1.85.  If this is a bug in s3fs it may be better to file a GitHub issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the rsync --inplace flag (instead of the temp_dir workaround), as per the writeup here:

https://baldnerd.com/preventing-rsync-from-doubling-or-even-tripling-your-s3-fees/